# Morphological operations merges lines with edges of pictures

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image with nearly constant lines in it and I use algorythm with morphological operations to clear them out of the image. The thing is, that morphological opening or closing merges the lines with the edges of the image instead of only just melting the neighbor contours. I need only neighbor contours melted with morphological operations and to avoid that line merging with edge, because later I am unable to clear that merged peace of the line out of the image. The problem stays even if I invert the image and morph. operations (image pixels black to white, white to black, and instead of opening I use close).

**How to stop this?**

I use this operation to merge neighbor contours:

```
Mat morphKernelClose = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new org.opencv.core.Size(25, 25));
Imgproc.morphologyEx(src, src, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernelClose);
```

**Simple Canny image:**

[image]

**Image after using MORPH_CLOSE:**

[image]

This error does not allow me to clear the lines fully (those merged parts are left) by using second morphology operation, opposite to used first.

Comment: The c++ version of morphologyEx has parameters for handling the border. Not sure whether they exist in java (?) version, too.

Comment: Thank you. There is a function overload in Java: `public static void morphologyEx(Mat src, Mat dst, int op, Mat kernel, Point anchor, int iterations, int borderType, Scalar borderValue)`, where "**borderType - Pixel extrapolation method. See "borderInterpolate" for details.**" and "**borderValue - Border value in case of a constant border. The default value has a special meaning. See "createMorphologyFilter" for details.**" So will this function overload allow me to manipulate the merging with borders with proper arguments? I can't find any sources using and explaining the usage of this.

Comment: I guess yes. just try it. set it to border_constant and value to 0.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it did work. Post it as an answer so others could with the same problem could be rescued and I could give you acceptance and upvote. If you don't want to, I can do it. The modified line: `Imgproc.morphologyEx(src, src, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernelClose, new Point(morphKernelClose.size().width/2, morphKernelClose.size().height/2), 1, Core.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(0,0,0));`. It just basically cuts off the parts near the border of the image (that is ok for me), but does not leave that part as it were.

Comment: please write the answer yourself with all the information needed (and maybe result images). You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **FiReTiTi** and **Micka** for helping me to solve this. I used Micka's suggestion.

I used the third function of morphologyEx, which allows to manipulate the borders. The code given in the question is replaced with this one:

```
Mat morphKernelClose = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new org.opencv.core.Size(25, 25));
Point anchor = new Point(morphKernelClose.size().width/2, morphKernelClose.size().height/2); 
Imgproc.morphologyEx(src, src, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernelClose, anchor, 1, Core.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(0,0,0));
```

**Here is the result:**
[image]

This method may be fast and easy, but not perfect, because it just cuts off the pixels near the borders.

**If you have any suggestions how to improve this, post it in the comments!**

Comment: The border effects are always a pain, and very difficult to avoid. In you case, the only solution I see would be to extend each line before processing, but it would mean to find all of them first, their orientation as well, and finally extend them. I don't think it worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to increase the image size, fill the added contour with black, and then perform the operations:

1. Create a bigger image, completely black.
2. Copy your image in the middle of the new image.
3. Perform the operations
4. Delete the border added (copy the center of the image into a new one).

Comment: instead of back-copying, a subimage could be used.